# How do i use JQuery Ajax to call a PHP file on the server side to return and execute javascripts?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

The client website needs to do a cross-domain JQuery Ajax call to a php file on my server, the php file will query the database for a bunch of stored javascripts which then need to be sent back to the client and be executed on the client's website. This is what i have so far, haven't done the grabbing javascript from database yet and it works. Is this the best way to do this (assuming i can grab the javascripts directly from the database without adding the escape sequence when echo'ing back to the client)? Thanks.

This is what i have so far:

```
 client side:
      $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:8888/test.php",
      dataType: "script",
      });

 server side (test.php):
      <?php
      echo "alert(\"WORKS!\");";
      ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Review the [ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and handle the `success` callback option on the `ajax` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8888/test.php",
    dataType: "html",
    success : function(data) { alert(data); }
});
```

As noted by Ricardo, your `PHP script` should echo `HTML` or some other content appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: I'd only add that the test.php should simply echo out data, and shouldn't really have javascript in it.

Comment: This part [echo "alert(\"WORKS!\");";] was just an example. In reality the javascript will be grabbed from the database and echoed to the client(i.e. the [alert("works")] would be in a variable and echoed back to the client).

Comment: And can the echoed html also have javascript?

Comment: yes, there can be `JavaScript` in the response. If you use a jQuery method like `.html(data)` it will be evaluated...

Answer (score 1):

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

And http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/